# Select <a> which href ends with some string

Tags: jquery, string, anchor, href

Is it possible using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to select all `<a>` links which href ends with "ABC"?

For example, if I want to find this link `<a href="http://server/page.aspx?id=ABC">`

Answer (score 1637, accepted):

```
   $('a[href$="ABC"]')...
```

Selector documentation can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

For attributes:

```
= is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= is starts with
$= is ends with
*= is contains
~= is contains word
|= is starts with prefix (i.e., |= "prefix" matches "prefix-...")
```

Comment: something changed recently.  $('[href$=-abc]') used to work. Now it requires quotes $('[href$="-abc"]')  I don't know when it changed. Maybe it was always supposed to require quotes and just happened to work before.

Comment: Note that "ABC" is case-sensitive! (Just spent quite some time to figure that one out...)

Comment: How to get href does not contains ABC in jquery

Comment: @sf.dev `$('a').filter(function() { return !this.href || !this.href.match(/ABC/); });`

Comment: This works with vanilla javascirpt now. You can simply use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="ABC"]')` to achieve this.

Comment: `!=` is not a valid attribute selector

Comment: @bitten the question is about jQuery attribute selectors. It is a valid conditional operation in jQuery.

Comment: if someone is trying to use a `var`
`var name = "ABC";
$('a[href$='+name+']')`

Answer (score 24):

```
$('a[href$="ABC"]:first').attr('title');
```

This will return the title of the first link that has a URL which ends with "ABC".

Comment: Correction: Which ends with ABC

Comment: Actually, there is a slight difference. This will select the first link with given href, which is useful if you need to change only one.

Answer (score 16):

```
$("a[href*='id=ABC']").addClass('active_jquery_menu');
```

Comment: For future visitors who may be helped by that answer.

Comment: @Sumit note that your answer is only correct if the OP's `ABC` happens to refer to an ID.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("a[href*=ABC]").addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you don't want to import a big library like jQuery to accomplish something this trivial, you can use the built-in method `querySelectorAll` instead. Almost all selector strings used for jQuery work with DOM methods as well:

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="ABC"]');
```

Or, if you know that there's only one matching element:

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('a[href$="ABC"]');
```

You may generally omit the quotes around the attribute value if the value you're searching for is alphanumeric, eg, here, you could also use

```
a[href$=ABC]
```

but quotes are more flexible and [generally more reliable](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values).