# Active links jquery superfish

Tags: jquery, menu, superfish

I have a question.
I use jquery superfish menu with the following structure

```
<div id="menu" class="ge-navigation-item">
  <!-- navigation -->
    <ul id="test" class="sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="proef.html">menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="page-fullwidth.php">Page - Full Width</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="showcase.php">Showcase</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /navigation -->
  </div>
```

what I want is that clicking on a link the menu structure will be visible

So clicking on index.html will set a link on all links with href index.html
But clicking on proef.html will set an active class on href proef.html - Page - About

So far I have tried this but with bad results

```
var path = window.location.toString().split("/")
path = path[path.length - 1]
//alert (path);
if (path)
$("#test a[href='" + path + "']").addClass("actief");
$("#test ul li:has(a) a[href='" + path +
     "']").parent().parent().parent().addClass("actief");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.  Try this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path[path.length-1];

if (path !== undefined) {
    $("#menu3").find("a[href='" + path + "']").addClass("actief");

}
```

That should appply the class to any link that matches the last item of the current url.  If you were looking for a different behavior, please elaborate!

**UPDATE**
Actually, it looks like you need this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path[path.length-1];

if (path !== undefined) {
    $("#menu3")
        .find("a[href$='" + path + "']") // gets all links that match the href
        .parents('li')  // gets all list items that are ancestors of the link
        .children('a')  // walks down one level from all selected li's
        .addClass('actief');
}
```

That will put the class on every `a` element up the chain.

Comment: This works but only for the active link. Clicking on proef.html should also set an active class on - Page - About
Thanks

Comment: I just made it far better.  You should update your script with my updated version.  I don't know why I went about it the way I did the first time.

Comment: I did that thanks. I added one small detail to it. if (!path) { path = 'index.html'; } so when no link is set the the default menu item is highlighted

Comment: Nice solution Stephen, I would just suggest small update where href is checked if **contains** not **match** path, because your solution doesn't work if link href has long path with more than one slash like this "something/something/page.htm".

Solution: `.find("a[href$='" + path + "']")`

Comment: Very nice answer! StackOverflow rocks... Adding to @Klikerko: here's the different selectors for attributes if someone's interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/303961/114029

Answer (score 1):

we did something like:

```
$("#sample-menu-1").find("a[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").each(function() {
$(this).parents('li').addClass("current");
$(this).closest('ul').css("visibility","visible").css("display","block");
});
```

It seems to work but on mousing over the menu, the menu doesn't hold the current position.

=== **update** ===

It seems the parent ul is reset to not display after mousing over the menu

Comment: Actually this solution is the best. The chosen answer has issue with nested menu. Thanks!