# add class to <a> if href starts with http://www.twitter.com/

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Select <a> which href contains some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string)

I am working on a little twitter implementation for a website.
The javascript I use exports the code as following:

```
<ul>
 <li>twitter message here <a href="http://twitter.com/username/ID">time of twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I like to add a class to the twitter link, so I can give it a different css then normal links inside the tweets.

Anyone got any thoughts how to fix this in a proper way? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/303956/106261

Comment: This question is about "starts with" not "contains'. The solution to the other would be `[href*='...']`or `[href$='...']` or so, but for this one is `[href^='...']`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('a[href^="http://twitter.com"]').addClass('twitter');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apjD6/

Comment: Your answer here also explained why my code wasn't working. I had space between the A and the [href....

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href^='http://twitter.com/']").addClass("someClass");
});
```

Check reference here:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Sorry, what was that? If the space between `a`, and '[', then fixed. Was it something else?

Comment: Your quotes were screwed up, I think. Fixed now, never mind ;)