# disable certain navigation links in popup window (external website)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am opening an external website in my pop window. I would like to disable certain links in that popup.

i.e. I am opening http://www.yahoo.com in pop and I want to disable some links in that pop-up so that who ever visit yahoo.com using my website, will not able to click on some links...

Is it possible? any idea?

Comment: Not possible, SOP prevents you from molesting anything from a different domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) your only option would be to load the page server side, abuse it there then serve it back.

Comment: hmm.. that is what i was thinking :) thanks

Comment: Sounds like a generel bad idea. But i guess you could load ex. yahoo.com with ajax and then disable links using regular jquery sorting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to run JavaScript on another domain because of the same origin policy. imagine someone opening up your bank account in a new window/frame and altering the links to transfer money to their account. ;)

You can screen scrape the content with your server and redisplay it, but you have to worry about proxying all of the relative links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a popup using the standard window.open you can manipulate the DOM of that document. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) for more information on how to do that (towards the bottom of the page). But this is fairly limiting to writing stuff to that page. I suppose you could render the link in an iframe and inject some javascript to manipulate it?