# Scan WebPage for Call to Action items

Tags: java, python, web-scraping

Given two URLs, where the second URL (URL2) was reached after performing some action on the first URL (URL1).

I wish to scan URL1 for possible call to action links/buttons which can lead to second URL. [I know the complete URL along with query parameters of both URLs]

What method/toolkit would you suggest as the best approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

If all links on page by URL1 is static links (not generated by js/serverside actions) then you could use for example jQuery and get all elements with href (forms with action) attribute like this:

```
$('a[href$="ABC"]')
$('form[action$="ABC"]')
```

Similar question: [Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string)

For python may be usefull will: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

Comment: Thanks I am looking in pyquery.

Comment: I ended up using BeautifulSoup in Python for extraction.