# Finding an <a> in a mess

Tags: php, dom

(I have to deal with this awful vendor site made for IE6)

I'm trying to find a way to dig out a link.

ex: `<a href="/part/id.aspx?v=449530">`, no matter where it may appear.

Basically, the first `<a>` beginning with `/part/id.aspx?v=`.

And extract the '449530'. There are no usable id's, classes, or anything, and the whole thing isn't valid HTML, XHTML, or XML.

Been going at it with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net to not much avail.

Any help is very much aprpeciated.

Comment: This thread will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("(/part/id\.aspx\?v=([0-9]+))",$data,$m);
$id = $m[1];
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression to find the element:

```
href=\"\/part-id\.aspx\?v=(?<id>\d+)\"
```