# How to get an element by ID based on a link's href with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, href, fadein

I'm trying to fade in a hidden element based on the `href` attribute of a clicked link but I can't figure out how, I tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/Zhn2W/

But for some reason `$(textBlock)` just returns an empty object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this` (which refer to the clicked anchor) instead of the intended element to find the text blocks. Try using `#text-blocks > div` selector instead:

```
// Fade out any visible text blocks
$('#text-blocks > div').fadeOut('normal', function() {
  // Fade in selected text block
  $(textBlock).fadeIn(); 
});
```

This is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhn2W/14/) of it.

**EDIT:**

Also you may want to avoid fadding in and out the already chosen element and in that case use `.not()`:

```
// Fade out any visible text blocks
$('#text-blocks > div').not(textBlock).fadeOut('normal', function() {
  // Fade in selected text block
  $(textBlock).fadeIn(); 
});
```

This is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhn2W/12/) of this edition.

Comment: Great that fixed the issue thanks, now I have to figure out why the div sometimes fades in twice really quick, any ideas? I updated your fiddle to better reflect how I'm actually using it http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/Zhn2W/13/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a[href="ABC"]').fadeIn();
```

Selector documentation can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

For attributes:

> = is exactly equal
>
> != is not equal
>
> ^= is starts with
>
> $= is ends with
>
> *= is contains

[Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string)

Comment: Not really trying to fade in the link but the div, eg. if I click the link with href `#text1` I want to fade in the div with id `text1`. Since the href already includes the `#` symbol I thought I could pass it to the jQuery function to select it :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code you're currently using is pretty simple. The selector you use to find the divs to fade out is:

```
$(this).find('div')
```

But in that context `this` refers to the element that was clicked on. Simply change that selector to:

```
$('#text-blocks').find('div')
```

And it should work.

EDIT:
Something else I noticed regarding your wrapper function. You missed the open-close parenthesis off the end, so none of your code is ever run. Alternatively to have it run on document ready you could prepend jQuery (or `$`) to the very start of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you forgot to add the first `$` in the jQuery ready call.  This is the JavaScript you need:

```
$(function(){
    $('#links a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Fade out any visible text blocks
        $('#text-blocks div').fadeOut();

        // Fade in required one
        $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); 

    });        
});​
```

jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhn2W/22/).