# Add rel to youtube links with jquery :contains

Tags: jquery, youtube, contains, attr, prettyphoto

I would like to add a rel to all links that contain a youtube link.
This is what I am working with - but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
$('a[href:contains("youtube.com")]').attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
```

I found a couple of other questions but not exactly like my request. This was the closest [Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/jquery-select-a-which-href-contains-some-string)
and posted my question there - but not sure if anyone would see it as it gets posted as an 'answer' not a question.

Comment: You should not post your question in answer section, please delete your question in that page.

Answer (score 3):

`:contains` selects all elements that contain the specified text, you should use [`Attribute Contains`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector instead.

```
$('a[href*="youtube.com"]').attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked like a charm. So in this case since I was using a href (an attribute) I needed to use the 'attribute contains'. But if I was not using an attribute I could have used the :contains? just making sure for future purposes like p:contains just as an example.

Comment: @ckinteractivedesign Yes, you can code `$('p:contains(something)')`.

Comment: great! thank you for your help. P.S. deletedmy question in the 'answers' on the other page.