# Apply css to certain <a> href in certain <div> (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
```

But there's two links on the page with that (variable) href. How do I apply it to one of them?

I've tried:

```
$('li a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
```

And:

```
$('#recent-posts a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
```

(where `#recent-posts` is the ul of the li s)

And:

```
$('#tunesID a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
```

(where `#tunesID` is the parent element of the URL)

Comment: Use `.eq(x)` where x is the index of the element.

Comment: ^^ or if there's only two, `first()` and `last()`

Comment: Can you post the html? Reason being, we need to see what differentiates each element in order to provide the best answer.

As indicated in the above comments, these are both usual methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function can be used to reduce the set of selected elements to the one at the specified index.  Just specify `0` or `1` for the `a` you want to select.

```
$('a[href$="' + currenturl2 + '"]').eq(0).css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it works. And if any other JQuery novices (like me) have the same problem and are reading this but are still stuck, make sure that you've got your attribute selector right (as I didn't at first)... Simple breakdown of those on this page: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string

Answer (score -1):

give to this links same class and in jquery code

```
$(".class").click(function(){
      $(this).css("font-family", "\'Apercu Bold\'");
});
```

Comment: This requires the user to click the element for the style to change. Not what the OP wants.

Comment: he's want apply css to certain <a> href in certain <div>, this links give him same class not all links in the page .

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all, but it still requires a click for it to work, which I'm sure he doesn't want. Kevin's answer using :eq() or .eq() is better.

Comment: you are the user1951962 ?
what you don't understand ?