# How to get all elements with a specified href attribute

Tags: javascript

Let say I've some elements with `href=/href_value/`attribute. How do I get all elements, such that their href attribute has the `href_value` value?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres a version that will work in old and new browsers by seeing if querySelectorAll is supported

You can use it by calling `getElementsByAttribute(attribute, value)`

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghRqV/

```
var getElementsByAttribute = function(attr, value) {
    if ('querySelectorAll' in document) {
        return document.querySelectorAll( "["+attr+"="+value+"]" )   
    } else {
        var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            result = []

        for (var i=0, _len=els.length; i < _len; i++) {
            var el = els[i]

            if (el.hasAttribute(attr)) {
                if (el.getAttribute(attr) === value) result.push(el)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

If you have the luxury of neglecting IE 7 or lower, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[href='href_value']");
```

Answer (score 21):

Maybe you need to get all the elements whose `href` value contain your specific `href_value`? If so, try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[href*="href_value"]');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) to search for all elements that match a CSS selector. This is supported by all modern browser versions.

In this case:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[href="href_value"]');
```