# Make parent dropdown link active when child is current page Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make parent dropdown link active when child is current page?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">Section3<b class="caret"></b>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#child1">Child1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#child2">Child2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a separate CSS file for your child page?

Answer (score 1):

After reading:

- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector),
- [Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string) and
- [Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

i think you can do this leveraging jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a[href$="' + $(location).attr('pathname') + '"]').parents('li.dropdown').addClass('active');
```

Depending on structure of your links in your menu items you should probably adopt  `$(location).attr('pathname')` to fit your needs.

Comment: could you please explain what is pathname? thank you

Comment: try http://www.bootply.com/8pjRS7eiUD, when you run it `$(location).attr('pathname')` will be equal to /run (set in the first dropdown `<li><a href="/run">Something else here</a></li>`)

Comment: Thank you! I think it doesn't work on a sinle page site. I am using fullpage.js jquery plugin.

Comment: fullpage.js use hashes as navigation link. In the above you can replace `$(location).attr('pathname')`  with `url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);`