# How to alter the [Edit node link] of views in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, view

I have added [edit node link] and [delete node link] in my view, which is rendered as

```
<a href="?q=node/52/edit&destination=product">Edit</a>
```

is there any hook (that's the elegant way) to alter the link to insert a font awesome icon before the link as below, thanks

```
<a href="?q=node/52/edit&destination=product"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: Can you output the path token as a url rather than a full link, then add the rest of the markup yourself? I am assuming you are adding the tokens to a textfield input in the view somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, 2pha. I cannot get the row link like "?q=node/52/edit&destination=product", the raw output of views contains the a element.

Comment: you could add the node id row, then use the [node:id] token

Comment: Thanks, that's a way if I ignore the destination. But I just wonder if there's any hook so that I could implement  with just a peace of code instead of changing every views.

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery for detecting those links (i.e. by "edit" word) and adding it some class. Something like described here:

[Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string)

Comment: Yes, that's one of the way to make a common script.