# Adding an id to a child with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some plugin-generated html that I can't change, and need to add an id to an `<a>` tag so that I can change it's `href` link.

#### HTML

```
<div id="wpmem_login">
   <form action="www.staging.com/login" method="POST" class="form">
      <fieldset>
         <!--other html fields-->
         <div align="right" class="link-text">
            <a href="www.staging.com/password_reset"> click to reset password</a>
         </div>
         <div align="right" class="link-text">
            <a href="www.staging.com/register"> click to register</a>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

(this code is form generated so I had to type from looking at inspect element, so there are more html fields above these two where I commented and any typos there may be really aren't relevant)

I need to change the href link on the second to last field, password reset, without touching the last link that has identical classes.  I know I can do this with `$("#reset").attr("href", "http://www.staging.com/pwd_reset")` once I have an id or selector `#reset` on that div, but I'm not sure how to get that selector.

I need help adding an id or getting the `.attr` function to the right link.

Comment: What have you tried? would suggest using `$(element-selector).prop('id');`

Comment: Whatever selector you use to find the link to add the ID to it, you can use the same selector to change its href in the first place. You don't need an ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a[href$="password_reset"]')
```

In otherwords find the anchor tag which *ends* with correct url.  Jquery allows some pattern matching capability so can hard code as little of url as possible.

Here is an SO that has details on the pattern matching capability in jquery

[Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can select your anchor using the href attribute:

```
   $('a[href="www.staging.com/password_reset"]').attr("href", "http://www.staging.com/pwd_reset")
```

After changing the href, to reselect the same element you need to change your jQuery selector to:

```
$('a[href="http://www.staging.com/pwd_reset"]')
```

Comment: @Barmar can do the same thing with any: `$("a[href='www.staging.com/password_reset']).prop('id', 'reset');`

Comment: I know. I just meant your method is correct, but the example is wrong for the question he asked.

Comment: What are you talking about? Nothing generates IDs automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I'm tired. you are rigth

Answer (score 0):

Just use the solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/303961/3866019
to select the right link. For you this would be something like:

```
$('a[href*="password_reset"]')
```

where `*=` means 'contains'
 and then use `.attr('id', 'reset')` to set it's id.

jQuery Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$` endsWith Selector to get your link and then change `href`

```
$('a[href$="password_reset"]').attr("href", "http://www.staging.com/pwd_reset");
```